# Cannot apply data source from other project to gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, gridview, visual-studio-2013

I have used asp.net for a few years now but today is the first time I've ever tried using the Designer view.

I attempted to add a gridview but cannot for the life of me get it to recognize my data source.

My data source is an entity framework .edmx in a separate project in the same solution that I have a reference to.   I've accessed it through other classes manually with no issues.

When trying to add the data source to the gridview the first error I got was

"the provider did not return a providermanifest instance"

I read that setting the Metadata Processing of the .edmx to "Copy to Output Directory" should fix this but then I get a different error:

"Unable to load the specified metadata resource"

I've read that maybe the connection string could be the issue but have had no luck with anything I've tried changing on it.  Here it is in it's current state:

```
<add name="ProjectEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/ProjectModel.csdl|res://*/ProjectModel.ssdl|res://*/ProjectModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=asdasd.com;initial catalog=asdasd;persist security info=True;user id=asdasd;password=asdasd;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have other providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connection string with above one? I mean you must have 2 connection strings in your app.config file.

Comment: The app config in the project that has the data source you mean?  If so it looks like this: `<add name="ProjectEntities" connectionString="metadata=.\ProjectModel.csdl|.\ProjectModel.ssdl|.\ProjectModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=asdasd.com;initial catalog=asdasd;persist security info=True;user id=asdasd;password=asdasd;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `<connectionStrings>` section should be like this:

```
<connectionStrings>
      <add name="ProjectEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/ProjectModel.csdl|res://*/ProjectModel.ssdl|res://*/ProjectModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=asdasd.com;initial catalog=asdasd;user id=asdasd;password=asdasd;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" 
     providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
<add name="SiteSqlServer"
  connectionString="Data Source=asdasd.com;Initial Catalog=asdasd;User ID=asdasd;Password=asdasd;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Application Name=EntityFramework"
  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Using the second connection string works perfectly!  Thank you very much.